# Condenser Mic Not Working

Tags: microphone, problem

I recently got a new mic since I am in a video game development course and I will need it for voice acting for my later projects. I have been trying to make it work, but not matter what I try it just won't give me any sound. I've tried different programs and visited many sites but nothing seems to work. So here is what I have for my mic setup

[Mic](http://www.amazon.ca/dp/B00NFCDESU/ref=pe_386430_121528420_TE_dp_3)

[Phantom Power](http://www.amazon.ca/dp/B000FG795I/ref=pe_386430_121528420_TE_dp_2)

Also my cable is "Your Cable Store 6 Foot XLR 3 Pin Male / Female Microphone Cable 28 AWG" (Can't post more than two links)

I've set this all up, made sure the phantom power was set to 48V and nothing seems to work. I tried it in my laptop as well as my PC and neither pick up sound.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So where do you plug the output of the phantom power supply ? Is there an audio input on your PC and laptop ? Possibly, you are trying to input a mic level signal into a line level input. You might have better result using a minimal usb interface with mic (and phantom) inputs.